# reading csv files over ssl with R

Tags: r, ssl, rcurl

Now that the whole world is clambering to use SSL all the time (a decision that makes a lot of sense) some of us who have used github and related services to store csv files have a little bit of a challenge. The read.csv() function does not support SSL when reading from a URL. To get around this I'm doing a little dance I like to call the SSL kabuki dance. I grab the text file with RCurl, write it to a temp file, then read it with read.csv(). Is there a smoother way of doing this? Better work-arounds?

Here's a simple example of the SSL kabuki:

```
require(RCurl)
myCsv <- getURL("https://gist.github.com/raw/667867/c47ec2d72801cfd84c6320e1fe37055ffe600c87/test.csv")
temporaryFile <- tempfile()
con <- file(temporaryFile, open = "w")
cat(myCsv, file = con) 
close(con)

read.csv(temporaryFile)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes -- see `help(download.file)` which is pointed to by `read.csv()` and all its cousins. The `method=` argument there has:

> `method`  Method to be used for downloading files. Currently download methods "internal", "wget", "curl" and "lynx" are available, and there is a value "auto": see ‘Details’. The method can also be set through the option "download.file.method": see options().

and you then use this option to `options()`:

> `download.file.method:`
>       Method to be used for download.file. Currently download methods "internal", "wget" and "lynx" are available. There is no default for this option, when method = "auto" is chosen: see download.file.

to turn to the *external program* `curl`, rather than the RCurl package.

*Edit*: Looks like I was half-right and half-wrong. `read.csv()` et al do *not* use the selected method, one needs to manually employ `download.file()` (which then uses `curl` or other selected methods).  Other functions that do use `download.file()` (such as package installation or updates) will profit from setting the option, but for JD's initial query concerning csv files over https, an explicit `download.file()` is needed before `read.csv()` of the downloaded file.

Comment: The help page for download.file says "https:// connections are not supported". Are you saying that specifying options(download.file.method="curl") will cure that problem?

Comment: Yes, as R will then 'farm out' to curl rather than using its own minimal http/ftp client code.

Comment: @DWin that help page states the line you quote refers only to `method = "internal"`.

Comment: Why in the world `download.file(testData, tmpFile, mode = 'wb', method = 'curl')`, where `testData` is a 4MB+ zip file, results in a 24KB file?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out: by default, GitHub truncates large files in a repository. Full file is available by adding `?raw=true` to the URL.

Comment: Note that if you get the unsupported connection error, make sure that "curl" is installed on the system.

Answer (score 14):

No need to write it to a file - just use textConnection()

```
require(RCurl)
myCsv <- getURL("https://gist.github.com/raw/667867/c47ec2d72801cfd84c6320e1fe37055ffe600c87/test.csv")
WhatJDwants <- read.csv(textConnection(myCsv))
```

Comment: I need to name more objects "WhatJDwants". Thanks for showing me how to use textConnection()

Answer (score 12):

Using Dirk's advice to explore `method=""` resulted in this slightly more concise approach which does not depend on the external RCurl package.

```
temporaryFile <- tempfile()
download.file("https://gist.github.com/raw/667867/c47ec2d72801cfd84c6320e1fe37055ffe600c87/test.csv",destfile=temporaryFile, method="curl")
read.csv(temporaryFile)
```

But it appears that I can't just set `options("download.file.method"="curl")`

Comment: Looks good. And I by using `tempfile()` that way, you use `tempdir()` so that the file will get purged when R exists its session.

Answer (score 6):

R core should open up the R connections as a C API. I've proposed this in the past:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2006-October/043056.html

with no response.

Comment: Very true and an issue we better get resolved one day, but not strictly speaking related the the question here, is it? ;-)

Comment: Yes, it's related, because one can make an https ssl connection using the proposed Connections API. That way, one could use url("https://..."), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Given that this question comes up a lot, I've been working on a package to seamlessly handle HTTPS/SSL data. The package is called **rio**. A version of it is on CRAN but the newest version that now supports this [is only available on GitHub](https://github.com/leeper/rio). Once you've installed the package, you can read in data in one line:

```
# install and load rio
library("devtools")
install_github("leeper/rio")
library("rio")

# import
import("https://gist.github.com/raw/667867/c47ec2d72801cfd84c6320e1fe37055ffe600c87/test.csv")
##   a b
## 1 1 2
## 2 2 3
## 3 3 4
## 4 4 5
```

Basically, `import` handles the manual download (using curl) and then infers the file format from the file extension, thus creating a dataframe without needing to know what function to use or how to download it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that since Dropbox changed the way that they present links with https:// none of the above solutions work any more.  Fortunately, I wasn't the first to make this discovery, and a solution was posted by Christopher Gandrud on r-bloggers:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/dropbox-r-data/

That approach works for me, after installing the repmis package and its dependencies.